# JavaScript logic - Parsing a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing, textarea

I need to take a textbox that is full of formatted info about accounts and then sort it somehow. I would like to know if it would be ideal (I'm trying to make this as efficient as possible) to parse the info into a two dimensional array, or if I should make account objects that will hold info in fields.

The program is simply meant to format the data so that it can be printed out without having to copy/paste.

So far I have...

```
function generateOutputfvoc()
{
    var accountLines = document.getElementById('accountLines').value;
    var accountLinesTemp = accountLines.split(/[\s]/);

    for(var i = 0; i < accountLinesTemp.length; i++)
    {
        if(accountLinesTemp[i].match(/
```

Edit (1-18-13): Here is an example input. It is basically text copied from a web CRM tool. Note, this example input is something I typed up randomly.

```
P8B000001234567     stackoverflow   Thing   12522225555     444         Active 2005-02-26   CO1000123456     
P8B000001234568     stackoverflow   Another Thing       444         Active  2005-02-26  CO1000123456     
P8B000001234569     stackoverflow   Another Thing       556         Active  2005-02-26  CO1000123456
```

I would like my program to take the text and simply output the text like this:

```
P8B000001234567 stackoverflow Thing         12522225555 444 Active 2005-02-26 CO1000123456
P8B000001234568 stackoverflow Another Thing             444 Active 2005-02-26 CO1000123456
P8B000001234569 stackoverflow Another Thing             556 Active 2005-02-26 CO1000123456
```

Also, I would like to know if I should use jQuery variables. I asked this because I have been looking online a lot and I found examples that use code that looks like this:

```
$check=fcompcheck();
if($check)
{
    $output=document.frm1.type.value+" / ";
    $output=$output+"Something - "+document.frm1.disco.value+" / ";
```

Note the: $output variable. The dollar sign indicates a jQuery variable, right?

Thank you for any help you might be able to offer me.

Update (1-19-13): I've taken a shot at it, but I'm making slow progress. I'm used to programming Java and my JavaScript looks too similar, I can tell I'm makings errors.

I'm taking it one step at a time. Here is the logic I'm using now.

- Person pastes text into text box and pushes the generate button
- Program takes the contents of the text box and parses it into a large array, removing only whitespace
- Program then searches for patterns in the text and begins passing values into variables

I am trying to get the program to simply identify the pattern "Summary section collapse Name" because these four words should always be in this sequence. Once it identifies this it will pass the next two array values into first and last name variables. Here's some of the code:

```
var contactNameFirst, contactNameLast;

// Parse the input box into an array
var inputArr = document.getElementById('inputBox').value.split(/[\s]/);

for(var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++)
{
    if(inputArr[i] == "Summary" && inputArr[i - 1] == "section" && inputArr[i - 2] == "Collapse" && inputArr[i + 1] == "Name")
    {
        if(inputArr[i + 2] != "Details")
        {
            contactNameFirst = inputArr[i + 2];
        }
        else
        {
            contactNameFirst = "";
        }
        if(inputArr[i + 3] != "Details")
        {
            contactNameLast = inputArr[i + 3];
        }
        else
        {
            contactNameLast = "";
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('contactNameOutput').innerHTML = contactNameFirst + " " + contactNameLast;
```

Also, should I create a new post for this now, or keep editing this one?

Comment: Can you post all of your code, it looks like some of it is missing after the 2nd `if` line? Also, regards jQuery, without knowing what the rest of your code is doing, it's harder to suggest whether you need to make use of it.

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net? What do you mean by jQuery variables?

Comment: More important, an example input and expected output is needed

Comment: I edited the original post and added examples. Thank you.

Comment: the $ in a var name is just a convention, it doesn't *do* anything. Also, for this type of thing, instead of parsing input from text areas, why not have groups of text boxes, and offer functionality to add new groups so that the form can handle any amount of data?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The point of my program is to make a procedure easier and more efficient. I would like the program to be as efficient as possible, but the user needs to be able to paste in text once, then get an output that can be highlighted and copied easily. It has to be this four step process. Paste, generate, highlight, copy.

Comment: Hmm, I'm new to Stack Overflow... Is this a bump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `accountLinesTemp` is an `Array` of `String`, you could use the `Array.sort` function to sort your array as expected, and then use `Array.join` to get the full String if necessary.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort on MDN for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll look into this first.